# Quarkus and how to implement in-memory, entities and DAO

Tags: java, derby, dao, quarkus, in-memory

I'm currently migrating my database layer (entity and DAO) from JavaEE to Quarkus (or well, from wls to OpenShift) and can't quite get my head around some details:

At the moment I have the current structure:

- Information class RegisteredTime.java
- Entity class defining column names and such, RegisteredTimeEntity.java, with matching persistence.xml
- MapStruct mapper class to map between RegisteredTime.java and RegisteredTimeEntity.java
- DAO-class to make db-access easier, RegisteredTimeDAO.java
- structure.ddl to define DB-structure
- In-memory class TestDB.java which extends JdbcDaoSupport (springframework) and uses Derby

My test class RegisteredTimeDAOTest which uses TestDB for in-memory:

```
class RegisteredTimeDAOTest extends Specification {

private RegisteredTimeId registeredTimeId;
private RegisteredTimeData registeredTimeData;

private long userId;
private int userVersion;
private RegisteredTime registeredTime;
private Long userNumber;
private LocalDate startDate, endDate
private Boolean registration
private Boolean registrationApproved
private String registration
private String timeType
private LocalDate incomingDate

@Shared
private EntityManager entityManager
@Shared
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
@Shared
private TestDB db
static SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource
private RedovisadTidEntity registeredTimeEntity
private RegisteredTimeDAO instance
private Gson gson

def setupSpec() {
    db = new TestDB("test")
    db.start()
    dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource(db.getJDBCUrl(), true)

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EKN-Persistence-Test")
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    if (entityManager != null) {
        entityManager.close()
    }
    if (entityManagerFactory != null) {
        entityManagerFactory.close()
    }
    db.shutdown()
}

def setup() {
    userId = 1
    userVersion = 1
    userNumber = 1991010101011L
    startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 01, 01)
    endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 01, 31)
    registration = false
    registrationApproved = false
    registration = null
    timeType = TimeType.STANDARD_TIME;
    incomingDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 02, 03)

    registeredTimeId = new RegisteredTimeId(userId, userVersion)
    registeredTimeData = RegisteredTimeData.newRegisteredTimeDataBuilder()
            .userNumber(userNumber)
            .startDate(startDate)
            .endDate(endDate)
            .registration(registration)
            .registrationApproved(registrationApproved)
            .timeType(timeType)
            .incomingDate(incomingDate)
            .build()

    registeredTime = new RegisteredTime().newRedovisadTidBuilder()
            .registeredTimeId(registeredTimeId)
            .registeredTimeData(registeredTimeData)
            .build()

    registeredTimeEntity = RegisteredTimeMapper.INSTANCE.toRegisteredTimeEntity(registeredTime)
    instance = new RegisteredTimeDAO(entityManager)
}

def cleanup() {
    instance = null
}

def "Save RegisteredTime"() {
    given:
    Statement statement = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement()
    statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM registeredtime")
    ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet()
    gson = new Gson()

    when:
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin()
    instance.save(registeredTime)
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit()

    then:
    while (rs.next()) {
        assert rs.getInt(2) == userVersion
        assert rs.getLong(3) == userNumber
        assert gson.fromJson(rs.getString(4), RegisteredTimeData.class).equals(registeredTimeData)
        assert rs.getTime(5) != null
    }
}

def "Get RegisteredTime"() {
    when:
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin()
    RegisteredTime registeredTimeGet = instance.get(1000, userVersion)
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit()

    then:
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeId().getAnsokanId() == userId
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeId().getAnsokanVersion() == userVersion
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getKundId() == userNumber
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getFromdatum() == startDate
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getTomdatum() == endDate
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getAnmalanAF() == registration
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getFranvarogodkandAF() == registrationApproved
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getTimeType() == timeType
    assert registeredTimeGet.getRegisteredTimeData().getAngavsviddatum() == incomingDate
}
```

}

I've been lurking around at quarkus.io and read the following:

https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource

https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm (probably the most important one)

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started (ofc)

https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling (using gradle)

- An entity class is still required, but EntityManagerFactory is being taken care off and Datasource and EntityManger can just be injected, right?
- Will I have to rewrite my TestDB or is there an "out of the box" solution? I looked at Zero Config Setup (DevServices), but this doesn't allow me to configure the db. I don't want to extend springframework anymore.
- Do I need a DAO if I use Hibernate WITHOUT Panache?

Comment: I, there is multiple question and to be sure that I didn't give a wrong answer can you explain what is your test class. It looks like Groovy (which is not supported by Quarkus) and a Spock test?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using Spock for your tests.

Quarkus only support JUnit5, so you should try with Spock 2.0-M5 that is based on JUnit5 and if possible use the Quarkus JUnit5 support via its `quarkus-junit5` extension.

There is an issue for [Quarkus and Spock support](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6506), you can watch it.

Note that there is no support for Groovy nor Spock from Quarkus.

As an alternative, you can also try [this Quarkus Spock extension](https://rapidtransit.github.io/quarkus-spock/), no idea what's its state is, I only found it via a Google search.

Regarding your questions :

> An entity class is still required, but EntityManagerFactory is being
> taken care off and Datasource and EntityManger can just be injected,
> right?

If you are using the Quarkus Hibernate ORM extension, it's a regular Hibernate integration, so a JPA implementation, so you need to define JPA entity classes. Then you can inject an `EntityManager`. You can also inject a `Datasource` but it's better to use the `EntityManager` as it provides higher level integrations.

> Will I have to rewrite my TestDB or is there an "out of the box"
> solution? I looked at Zero Config Setup (DevServices), but this
> doesn't allow me to configure the db. I don't want to extend
> springframework anymore.

If you can use `@QuarkusTest` support, it will start your application so you can use a memory database like H2 or Derby. There is a test support to automatically starts an H2database via a Quarkus test ressource, see the [Starting services before the Quarkus application starts](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource) section of the Quarkus test guide that explains how to launch an H2 database thanks to `io.quarkus.test.h2.H2DatabaseTestResource`.

Devservices is also a good way to do it, it will run a real database inside a docker container, so if you didn't configure any datasource but use one of the Quarkus JDBC extensions (like `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql` for example), it will run a docker container in both dev and test for this database.

Two more things can help you achieve what you want: Quarkus has support for flyway or liquibase to manage database migration, and you can have specific test properties via the `%test` configuration profile (for exemple to run dedicated sql import file on test).

> Do I need a DAO if I use Hibernate WITHOUT Panache?

Well, if you need a DAO I suggest using Hibernate with Panache that is a nice extension that allows to easily implements a DAO on top of your entity. But it depends on how you want to design your application. It's up to you to use a DAO or not, and to use Hibernate with Panache for your DAO or not.